# Two-point function for a real scalar field with a derivative coupling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, perturbation-theory, correlation-functions

Consider the Lagrangian for a free real scalar in 4D
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu \phi -\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2.
\end{equation}

We add to this an interaction
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_\text{int} = \frac{g}{3!}\phi\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi.
\end{equation}

The corrections to the two-point function are given by the Gell-Mann-Low formula:
\begin{equation}
\langle\Omega |T(\phi(x_1) \phi(x_2)|\Omega \rangle = \langle 0|T(\phi_\text{in}(x_1) \phi_\text{in}(x_2)\exp\bigg(\frac{ig}{3!}\int \phi\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi d^4y\bigg))|0\rangle.
\end{equation}

Where $|\Omega\rangle$ is the interaction vacuum and $|0\rangle$ is the free vacuum.

My question is how do I derive the corrections up to the second order in the coupling? I think the first order corrections vanish due to there being an odd number of fields but the second order is non-vanishing. Following Matthew Schwartz QFT and the Standard Model (Chapter 7), I know that the derivative brings down $\pm ip_\mu$ where $p_\mu$ is the 4-momentum, with the sign depending on whether the particle is created or destroyed. But how do the usual Feynman rules translate in the position space?

It is my first time learning QFT so kindly excuse any naivety.